# How to solve the compiler error of USB debugging probe of C2000 series Texas Instrument Microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, debugging, texas-instruments, compiler

I am using Launchpad-F28027F to generate PWM for buck converter. I am currently using simple example of PWM from Resource Explorer of CCS but it's no working due to the error shown in the below mentioned pictures.

After flashing the code, all lights of launchpad turns on which might shows that code has been progressed but there is no output on oscilloscope.

After debuggung the status automatically changes to Suspended-SW Breakpoint and 3 points are highlighted in every example. The case in first picture is from main program (Example_2802xHRPWM.c), second error is from args_main.c and third is from boot28.asm. All there cases are mentioned with command below

First:
[image: main program]

Second:
[image: args_main.c]

Third:
[image: boot28.asm]

The main program is given by

```
//###########################################################################
//
// FILE:    Example_2802xHRPWM.c
//
// TITLE:   f2802x Device HRPWM example
//
// ASSUMPTIONS:
//
//
//    This program requires the f2802x header files.
//
//    Monitor ePWM1-ePWM4 pins on an oscilloscope as described
//    below.
//
//       ePWM1A is on GPIO0
//       ePWM1B is on GPIO1
//
//       ePWM2A is on GPIO2
//       ePWM2B is on GPIO3
//
//       ePWM3A is on GPIO4
//       ePWM3B is on GPIO5
//
//    As supplied, this project is configured for "boot to SARAM"
//    operation.  The 2802x Boot Mode table is shown below.
//    For information on configuring the boot mode of an eZdsp,
//    please refer to the documentation included with the eZdsp,
//
//    $Boot_Table
//    While an emulator is connected to your device, the TRSTn pin = 1,
//    which sets the device into EMU_BOOT boot mode. In this mode, the
//    peripheral boot modes are as follows:
//
//      Boot Mode:   EMU_KEY        EMU_BMODE
//                   (0xD00)         (0xD01)
//      ---------------------------------------
//      Wait         !=0x55AA        X
//      I/O          0x55AA          0x0000
//      SCI          0x55AA          0x0001
//      Wait         0x55AA          0x0002
//      Get_Mode     0x55AA          0x0003
//      SPI          0x55AA          0x0004
//      I2C          0x55AA          0x0005
//      OTP          0x55AA          0x0006
//      Wait         0x55AA          0x0007
//      Wait         0x55AA          0x0008
//      SARAM        0x55AA          0x000A   <-- "Boot to SARAM"
//      Flash        0x55AA          0x000B
//      Wait         0x55AA          Other
//
//   Write EMU_KEY to 0xD00 and EMU_BMODE to 0xD01 via the debugger
//   according to the Boot Mode Table above. Build/Load project,
//   Reset the device, and Run example
//
//   $End_Boot_Table
//
// DESCRIPTION:
//
//       This example modifies the MEP control registers to show edge
//       displacement due to the HRPWM control extension of the respective
//       EPwm module
//       All EPwm1A,2A,3A,4A channels (GPIO0, GPIO2, GPIO4, GPIO6) will have
//       fine edge movement due to HRPWM logic
//
//            1. PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=10),
//                 ePWM1A toggle low/high with MEP control on rising edge
//               PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=10),
//                 ePWM1B toggle low/high with NO HRPWM control
//
//            2. PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=20),
//                  ePWM2A toggle low/high with MEP control on rising edge
//               PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=20),
//                  ePWM2B toggle low/high with NO HRPWM control
//
//            3. PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=10),
//                 ePWM3A toggle as high/low with MEP control on falling edge
//               PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=10),
//                 ePWM3B toggle low/high with NO HRPWM control
//
//            4. PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=20),
//                  ePWM4A toggle as high/low with MEP control on falling edge
//               PWM Freq = SYSCLK/(period=20),
//                  ePWM4B toggle low/high with NO HRPWM control
//
//
//###########################################################################
// $TI Release: F2802x Support Library v3.03.00.00 $
// $Release Date: Tue May 26 17:09:17 IST 2020 $
// $Copyright:
// Copyright (C) 2009-2020 Texas Instruments Incorporated - http://www.ti.com/
//
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
// modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions 
// are met:
// 
//   Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
//   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
// 
//   Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
//   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the 
//   documentation and/or other materials provided with the   
//   distribution.
// 
//   Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of
//   its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
//   from this software without specific prior written permission.
// 
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS 
// "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
// LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
// A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT 
// OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, 
// SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
// LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
// DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
// THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT 
// (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE 
// OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
// $
//###########################################################################

//
// Included Files
//
#include "F2802x_Device.h"      // f2802x Headerfile
#include "common/include/f2802x_examples.h" // f2802x Examples Headerfile
#include "f2802x_epwm_defines.h"    // useful defines for initialization

//
// Function prototypes
//
void HRPWM1_Config(Uint16);
void HRPWM2_Config(Uint16);
void HRPWM3_Config(Uint16);
void HRPWM4_Config(Uint16);

//
// Globals
//
uint16_t i,j,DutyFine,n,update;
uint32_t temp;

//
// Main
//
void main(void)
{
    //
    // WARNING: Always ensure you call memcpy before running any functions from
    // RAM InitSysCtrl includes a call to a RAM based function and without a 
    // call to memcpy first, the processor will go "into the weeds"
    //
#ifdef _FLASH
    memcpy(&RamfuncsRunStart, &RamfuncsLoadStart, (size_t)&RamfuncsLoadSize);
#endif

    //
    // Step 1. Initialize System Control:
    // PLL, WatchDog, enable Peripheral Clocks
    // This example function is found in the f2802x_SysCtrl.c file.
    //
    InitSysCtrl();

    //
    // Step 2. Initialize GPIO:
    // This example function is found in the f2802x_Gpio.c file and
    // illustrates how to set the GPIO to it's default state.
    //
    //InitGpio();  // Skipped for this example
    
    //
    // For this case, just init GPIO for EPwm1-EPwm4
    //
    
    //
    // For this case just init GPIO pins for EPwm1, EPwm2, EPwm3, EPwm4
    // These functions are in the f2802x_EPwm.c file
    //
    InitEPwm1Gpio();
    InitEPwm2Gpio();
    InitEPwm3Gpio();
    InitEPwm4Gpio();

    //
    // Step 3. Clear all interrupts and initialize PIE vector table:
    // Disable CPU interrupts
    //
    DINT;

    //
    // Initialize the PIE control registers to their default state.
    // The default state is all PIE interrupts disabled and flags
    // are cleared.
    // This function is found in the f2802x_PieCtrl.c file.
    //
    InitPieCtrl();

    //
    // Disable CPU interrupts and clear all CPU interrupt flags
    //
    IER = 0x0000;
    IFR = 0x0000;

    //
    // Initialize the PIE vector table with pointers to the shell Interrupt
    // Service Routines (ISR).
    // This will populate the entire table, even if the interrupt
    // is not used in this example.  This is useful for debug purposes.
    // The shell ISR routines are found in f2802x_DefaultIsr.c.
    // This function is found in f2802x_PieVect.c.
    //
    InitPieVectTable();

    //
    // Step 4. Initialize all the Device Peripherals:
    // Not required for this example
    //

    //
    // For this example, only initialize the EPwm
    // Step 5. User specific code, enable interrupts:
    //
    update =1;
    DutyFine =0;

    EALLOW;
    SysCtrlRegs.PCLKCR0.bit.TBCLKSYNC = 0;
    EDIS;

    //
    // Some useful Period vs Frequency values
    //  SYSCLKOUT =     60 MHz       40 MHz
    //  
    //  Period          Frequency    Frequency
    //  1000            60 kHz       40 kHz
    //  800             75 kHz       50 kHz
    //  600             100 kHz      67 kHz
    //  500             120 kHz      80 kHz
    //  250             240 kHz      160 kHz
    //  200             300 kHz      200 kHz
    //  100             600 kHz      400 kHz
    //  50              1.2 Mhz      800 kHz
    //  25              2.4 Mhz      1.6 MHz
    //  20              3.0 Mhz      2.0 MHz
    //  12              5.0 MHz      3.3 MHz
    //  10              6.0 MHz      4.0 MHz
    //  9               6.7 MHz      4.4 MHz
    //  8               7.5 MHz      5.0 MHz
    //  7               8.6 MHz      5.7 MHz
    //  6               10.0 MHz     6.6 MHz
    //  5               12.0 MHz     8.0 MHz

    //
    // ePWM and HRPWM register initialization
    //
    HRPWM1_Config(10);      // ePWM1 target, Period = 10
    HRPWM2_Config(20);      // ePWM2 target, Period = 20
    HRPWM3_Config(10);      // ePWM3 target, Period = 10
    HRPWM4_Config(20);      // ePWM4 target, Period = 20

    EALLOW;
    SysCtrlRegs.PCLKCR0.bit.TBCLKSYNC = 1;
    EDIS;

    while (update ==1)
    {
        for(DutyFine =1; DutyFine <256 ;DutyFine ++)
        {
            //
            // Example, write to the HRPWM extension of CMPA
            //
            
            //
            // Left shift by 8 to write into MSB bits
            //
            EPwm1Regs.CMPA.half.CMPAHR = DutyFine << 8;
            
            //
            // Left shift by 8 to write into MSB bits
            //
            EPwm2Regs.CMPA.half.CMPAHR = DutyFine << 8;

            // Example, 32-bit write to CMPA:CMPAHR
            EPwm3Regs.CMPA.all = ((Uint32)EPwm3Regs.CMPA.half.CMPA << 16) + 
                                  (DutyFine << 8);
            EPwm4Regs.CMPA.all = ((Uint32)EPwm4Regs.CMPA.half.CMPA << 16) + 
                                  (DutyFine << 8);

            for (i=0;i<10000;i++)
            {
                //
                // Dummy delay between MEP changes
                //
            }
        }
    }
}

//
// HRPWM1_Config -
//
void
HRPWM1_Config(Uint16 period)
{
    //
    // ePWM1 register configuration with HRPWM
    // ePWM1A toggle low/high with MEP control on Rising edge
    //
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.PRDLD = TB_IMMEDIATE;   // set Immediate load
    EPwm1Regs.TBPRD = period-1;                 // PWM frequency = 1 / period
    EPwm1Regs.CMPA.half.CMPA = period / 2;      // set duty 50% initially
    EPwm1Regs.CMPA.half.CMPAHR = (1 << 8);      // initialize HRPWM extension
    EPwm1Regs.CMPB = period / 2;                // set duty 50% initially
    EPwm1Regs.TBPHS.all = 0;
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTR = 0;

    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.CTRMODE = TB_COUNT_UP;
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.PHSEN = TB_DISABLE;     // EPwm1 is the Master
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.SYNCOSEL = TB_SYNC_DISABLE;
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.HSPCLKDIV = TB_DIV1;
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.CLKDIV = TB_DIV1;

    EPwm1Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADAMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm1Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADBMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm1Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWAMODE = CC_SHADOW;
    EPwm1Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWBMODE = CC_SHADOW;

    EPwm1Regs.AQCTLA.bit.ZRO = AQ_CLEAR;        // PWM toggle low/high
    EPwm1Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAU = AQ_SET;
    EPwm1Regs.AQCTLB.bit.ZRO = AQ_CLEAR;
    EPwm1Regs.AQCTLB.bit.CBU = AQ_SET;

    EALLOW;
    EPwm1Regs.HRCNFG.all = 0x0;
    EPwm1Regs.HRCNFG.bit.EDGMODE = HR_REP;      // MEP control on Rising edge
    EPwm1Regs.HRCNFG.bit.CTLMODE = HR_CMP;
    EPwm1Regs.HRCNFG.bit.HRLOAD  = HR_CTR_ZERO;
    EDIS;
}

//
// HRPWM2_Config - 
//
void
HRPWM2_Config(Uint16 period)
{
    //
    // ePWM2 register configuration with HRPWM
    // ePWM2A toggle low/high with MEP control on Rising edge
    //
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.PRDLD = TB_IMMEDIATE;     // set Immediate load
    EPwm2Regs.TBPRD = period-1;                   // PWM frequency = 1 / period
    EPwm2Regs.CMPA.half.CMPA = period / 2;        // set duty 50% initially
    EPwm1Regs.CMPA.half.CMPAHR = (1 << 8);        // initialize HRPWM extension
    EPwm2Regs.CMPB = period / 2;                  // set duty 50% initially
    EPwm2Regs.TBPHS.all = 0;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTR = 0;

    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.CTRMODE = TB_COUNT_UP;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.PHSEN = TB_DISABLE;       // EPwm2 is the Master
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.SYNCOSEL = TB_SYNC_DISABLE;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.HSPCLKDIV = TB_DIV1;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.CLKDIV = TB_DIV1;

    EPwm2Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADAMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm2Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADBMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm2Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWAMODE = CC_SHADOW;
    EPwm2Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWBMODE = CC_SHADOW;

    EPwm2Regs.AQCTLA.bit.ZRO = AQ_CLEAR;          // PWM toggle low/high
    EPwm2Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAU = AQ_SET;
    EPwm2Regs.AQCTLB.bit.ZRO = AQ_CLEAR;
    EPwm2Regs.AQCTLB.bit.CBU = AQ_SET;

    EALLOW;
    EPwm2Regs.HRCNFG.all = 0x0;
    EPwm2Regs.HRCNFG.bit.EDGMODE = HR_REP;        // MEP control on Rising edge
    EPwm2Regs.HRCNFG.bit.CTLMODE = HR_CMP;
    EPwm2Regs.HRCNFG.bit.HRLOAD  = HR_CTR_ZERO;

    EDIS;
}

//
// HRPWM3_Config -
//
void
HRPWM3_Config(Uint16 period)
{
    //
    // ePWM3 register configuration with HRPWM
    // ePWM3A toggle high/low with MEP control on falling edge
    //
    EPwm3Regs.TBCTL.bit.PRDLD = TB_IMMEDIATE;    // set Immediate load
    EPwm3Regs.TBPRD = period-1;                  // PWM frequency = 1 / period
    EPwm3Regs.CMPA.half.CMPA = period / 2;       // set duty 50% initially
    EPwm3Regs.CMPA.half.CMPAHR = (1 << 8);       // initialize HRPWM extension
    EPwm3Regs.TBPHS.all = 0;
    EPwm3Regs.TBCTR = 0;

    EPwm3Regs.TBCTL.bit.CTRMODE = TB_COUNT_UP;
    EPwm3Regs.TBCTL.bit.PHSEN = TB_DISABLE;      // EPwm3 is the Master
    EPwm3Regs.TBCTL.bit.SYNCOSEL = TB_SYNC_DISABLE;
    EPwm3Regs.TBCTL.bit.HSPCLKDIV = TB_DIV1;
    EPwm3Regs.TBCTL.bit.CLKDIV = TB_DIV1;

    EPwm3Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADAMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm3Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADBMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm3Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWAMODE = CC_SHADOW;
    EPwm3Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWBMODE = CC_SHADOW;

    EPwm3Regs.AQCTLA.bit.ZRO = AQ_SET;           // PWM toggle high/low
    EPwm3Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAU = AQ_CLEAR;
    EPwm3Regs.AQCTLB.bit.ZRO = AQ_SET;
    EPwm3Regs.AQCTLB.bit.CBU = AQ_CLEAR;

    EALLOW;
    EPwm3Regs.HRCNFG.all = 0x0;
    EPwm3Regs.HRCNFG.bit.EDGMODE = HR_FEP;       // MEP control on falling edge
    EPwm3Regs.HRCNFG.bit.CTLMODE = HR_CMP;
    EPwm3Regs.HRCNFG.bit.HRLOAD  = HR_CTR_ZERO;
    EDIS;
}

//
// HRPWM4_Config - 
//
void
HRPWM4_Config(Uint16 period)
{
    //
    // ePWM4 register configuration with HRPWM
    // ePWM4A toggle high/low with MEP control on falling edge
    //
    EPwm4Regs.TBCTL.bit.PRDLD = TB_IMMEDIATE;    // set Immediate load
    EPwm4Regs.TBPRD = period-1;                  // PWM frequency = 1 / period
    EPwm4Regs.CMPA.half.CMPA = period / 2;       // set duty 50% initially
    EPwm4Regs.CMPA.half.CMPAHR = (1 << 8);       // initialize HRPWM extension
    EPwm4Regs.CMPB = period / 2;                 // set duty 50% initially
    EPwm4Regs.TBPHS.all = 0;
    EPwm4Regs.TBCTR = 0;

    EPwm4Regs.TBCTL.bit.CTRMODE = TB_COUNT_UP;
    EPwm4Regs.TBCTL.bit.PHSEN = TB_DISABLE;      // EPwm4 is the Master
    EPwm4Regs.TBCTL.bit.SYNCOSEL = TB_SYNC_DISABLE;
    EPwm4Regs.TBCTL.bit.HSPCLKDIV = TB_DIV1;
    EPwm4Regs.TBCTL.bit.CLKDIV = TB_DIV1;

    EPwm4Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADAMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm4Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADBMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm4Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWAMODE = CC_SHADOW;
    EPwm4Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWBMODE = CC_SHADOW;

    EPwm4Regs.AQCTLA.bit.ZRO = AQ_SET;           // PWM toggle high/low
    EPwm4Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAU = AQ_CLEAR;
    EPwm4Regs.AQCTLB.bit.ZRO = AQ_SET;
    EPwm4Regs.AQCTLB.bit.CBU = AQ_CLEAR;

    EALLOW;
    EPwm4Regs.HRCNFG.all = 0x0;
    EPwm4Regs.HRCNFG.bit.EDGMODE = HR_FEP;       // MEP control on falling edge
    EPwm4Regs.HRCNFG.bit.CTLMODE = HR_CMP;
    EPwm4Regs.HRCNFG.bit.HRLOAD  = HR_CTR_ZERO;
    EDIS;
}

//
// End of File
//
```

Comment: I don't see any compiler error. Do you mean the last message? This is quite common to have not frame information, please learn about "stack frames".

Comment: But due to this I am not able to get any output.. USB debug probe suspended

Comment: Why do you think you have a compiler error? What is the compiler's error message?

Comment: The error is USB debug probe Suspended. Due to which 3 breakpoints occurs. How to resolve that?

Comment: This is not from the **compiler**, and it is no **error**. It is a **message** from the **debugger**, and no error at all. Please look into your project's preferences, many debuggers have an option to stop the debugged application right at the beginning of `main()`. And it looks as if this is the case here.

Comment: Ok Fine. But then why I am unable to get any output?

Comment: Without any source code and schematic, nobody can tell. Did you take the [tour] and read "[ask]"? Please provide enough context so that we don't need to use our crystal balls. They are in Corona quarantine. Did you follow the mentioned example's tutorial step by step?

Comment: Please add new information to your question. Don't provide them here in the comments!

Comment: Please format your code to become readable.

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but the CCS debug window looks normal to me.  Once you begin debugging, and the debugger halts on the breakpoints you listed above, have you tried hitting "continue" (the green arrow) to get the program to resume?